# php hashing - trying to add a sign up page to add to database with hashing

Tags: php, hash, sign

I'm trying to add password hashing. Am I doing this right? I've downloaded the password.php and required it in my sight up page.

Am I on the right track?

```
 if($oForm2-> valid == true){
        $oUser = new User();
        $oUser-> FirstName = $_POST["FirstName"];
        $oUser-> LastName = $_POST["LastName"];
        $oUser-> Email = $_POST["Email"];
        $oUser-> Password = password_hash($_POST["Password"],PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $oUser-> Password = $_POST["ConfirmPassword"];

        $_SESSION["UserID"] = $oUser-> UserID;

        $oUser->save();

        // re direction to the index once they have loged in.
        header("Location:http:myPortfolio.php?UserID=".$oUser->UserID);
        exit;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Can you post your `password.php`? To hash a password, all you should really need to do is `sha1()` it with a static salt you define in your code/configuration.

Answer (score 2):

```
$oUser-> Password = $_POST["ConfirmPassword"];
```

You don't need this. You have defined one line up allredy like hash string.